# Pandas ix method returning blank dataframe instead of desired result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to use the method here under "Removing rows that don't meet the desired criteria" to only include rows in my dataframe where column B's value is less than column C's: https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-delete-rows-from-a-DataFrame-in-Python-Pandas

It's not working though, and just returns a blank dataframe

So basically here's what it should look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import1 = pd.read_csv('./a_csv.csv')
import2 = pd.read_csv('./another_csv.csv')

df1 = import1[['A', 'B']]
df2 = import2[['A1', 'C']]

In[10]: df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='A', right_on='A1').drop('A1', axis=1)
Out[10]:
    A    B    C
a  01    2    2
b  02    5    6
c  03    8    8
d  04    1    5

In[11]: df = df.ix[~(df['B'] < df['C'])]
Out[11]:
    A    B    C
a  02    5    6
b  04    1    5
```

But line 11 isn't producing the desired result. What am I doing wrong? I would be open to using methods other than ix if they're easier or more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems

1. By using the `~` you are negating the mask.
2. `.ix` is used for indexing both by name and location. Generally you want to use `.loc` or `.iloc` unless you have a good reason not to. `.ix` is actually [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) because it can easily lead to really unexcpected results.

Instead of your line 11 try:

```
df.loc[df['B'] < df['C']]
```

This returns:

```
   A  B  C
b  2  5  6
d  4  1  5
```

Comment: That's just returning the original dataframe with no changes for me

Comment: @Alavar try doing this instead of your line 11.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. No changes to the dataframe in line 10. And when I try iloc I get the following error: `NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available
`

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.18.1

Comment: `iloc` won't work here since it's used for integer based indexing... Checkout the link in the answer to read more about when to use `iloc` vs. `loc`. Try updating your pandas and using `.loc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163368/discussion-between-alex-and-alavar).